# angular filter name as variable

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm designing universal table that reads data and columns from ajax.
In columns description is also filter name which angular should use for a specific column.
But in HTML templates I can't use variables for filter names:/
Is there a solution for that? Or should I code javascript loop with data source?

Here is code example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
    <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
        {{item[col.source]}}
        <span ng-if="col.ngFilter">
            {{col.ngFilter}} // ex. "state" filter
            {{item[col.source]|col.ngFilter}} //is not working - is looking for "col.ngFilter" not "state" filter.
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do it in your HTML. First, you need to apply the filter in your controller.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.applyFilter = function(model, filter) {
        return $filter(filter)(model);
    };

}
```

Then, in your HTML:

Instead of

```
{{item[col.source]|col.ngFilter}}
```

use

```
{{applyFilter(item[col.source], col.ngFilter)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for response - I put all filter handeling in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do something like

```
{{applyFliter(item[col.source], col.ngFilter)}}
```

where ngFilter might contains some colon separated parameters such as

```
currency:"USD$":0
```

I ended up writing this little helper

```
function applyFilter (model, filter){
    if(filter){

        var pieces = filter.split(':');

        var filterName = pieces[0];

        var params = [model];

        if(pieces.length>1){
            params = params.concat(pieces.slice(1));
        }

        return $filter(filterName).apply(this,params);
    }else{
        return model;
    }
}
```