# AngularJS merge directives

Tags: angularjs

I hate it when I repeat code. So I want to know if there is a better way of doing this.
I have 2 directives, they are very simple and very similar.
The 2 directives look like this:

```
.directive('pkFilterProducts', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/directives/pkFilterProducts.html',
        scope: {
            products: '=pkFilterProducts',
            filters: '='
        }
    }
})

.directive('pkStateProducts', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/directives/pkStateProducts.html',
        scope: {
            products: '=pkStateProducts',
            states: '='
        }
    }
})
```

The only difference is one accepts filters and the other accepts states.
The templates are very similar too:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Excluded ({{ excluded.length }})</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive" ng-show="excluded.length">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="image-column"></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in products | exclude: filters as excluded">
                    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" /></td>
                    <td>{{ product.shortTitle }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Included ({{ included.length }})</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive" ng-show="included.length">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="image-column"></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in products | include: filters as included">
                    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" /></td>
                    <td>{{ product.shortTitle }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Excluded ({{ excluded.length }})</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive" ng-show="excluded.length">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="image-column"></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in products | statesExclude: states as excluded">
                    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" /></td>
                    <td>{{ product.shortTitle }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Included ({{ included.length }})</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive" ng-show="included.length">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="image-column"></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in products | statesInclude: states as included">
                    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" /></td>
                    <td>{{ product.shortTitle }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

again, the only different is the **ng-repeat** filter. Instead of using **include** or **exclude** it uses **statesInclude** and **statesExclude**.
Is there a way I can combine these too? Maybe use a variable for the filter?

Comment: You can't use a variable for the filter. Unless you want to refactor filters and create custom filter that accepts 'mode' parameter and aggregates `include` and `stateInclude`, then no, there's no way. And tbh, the code doesn't cry for refactoring, I see no reason to ruin it with messy common denominator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710513/angular-filter-name-as-variable shows using filternames as variables

Comment: It is essentially the same thing as custom filter, just more awkward.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound a bit too hacky but I'd join the two ng-repeats on a single template and use ng-ifs to make them check for which is valid/should run. Example:

```
<tr ng-if="states"
    ng-repeat="product in products | statesInclude: states as included">
    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" /></td>
    <td>{{ product.shortTitle }}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="filters"
    ng-repeat="product in products | include: filters as included">
    <td><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" /></td>
    <td>{{ product.shortTitle }}</td>
</tr>
```

You could then perhaps use a single directive declaration:

```
.directive('pkProducts', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/directives/pkProducts.html',
        scope: {
            products: '=pkFilterProducts',
            filters: '=',
            states: '='
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: that doesn't really solve anything though, I am repeating html for all the ng-repeats :(

Answer (score 0):

I agree with wdanda.

Another solution would be to pass an boolean to your filter. Depending on the boolean you need to make it behave different.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments) for reference.